# Integrar Firebase en ionic v1

Tags: angularjs, ionic, firebase

Hola tengo problemas al integrar Firebase en mi app de ionic v1.

La forma  de como lo estoy integrando es la siguiente:

Creo un config.js:

```
angular.module('starter.configs', [])

.constant("CONFIG", {
  "FIREBASE_API": 'apiiiii******+',
  "FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN": 'caif-**a.firebaseapp.com',
  "FIREBASE_DB_URL": 'https://caif-a***a.firebaseio.com',
  "FIREBASE_STORAGE": 'caif-a**.appspot.com',
  "MESSAGE_SENDER_ID": '19128****'
});

importo firebase.js ,angularfire.js y config.js en el index.hrml:

<script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="lib/firebase/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angularfire/dist/angularfire.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/config.js"></script>
```

luego en app.js integro `firebase` y `starter.configs`.

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','starter.controllers','ngResource','firebase','starter.configs','starter.services'])
```

y por ultimo lo inicio de la siguiente manera en el mismo app.js

```
  .run(function($ionicPlatform,CONFIG) {
     $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

  if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {

    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);


  }
  if(window.StatusBar) {
    StatusBar.styleDefault();
  }

  firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: CONFIG.FIREBASE_API,
    authDomain: CONFIG.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: CONFIG.FIREBASE_DB_URL,
    storageBucket: CONFIG.FIREBASE_STORAGE,
    messagingSenderId: CONFIG.FIREBASE_STORAGE
  });


});
})
```

para utilizar por ejemplo `$firebaseAuth` en services creo lo siguiente:

```
.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",function($firebaseAuth) {
return $firebaseAuth();
}
])
```

y desde el controlador seria algo como así:

```
.controller('InicioCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Auth) {

  $scope.LoginUser = function(email, pass) {

    var email = email;
    var password = pass;

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(firebaseUser) {
  $location.path('tab/ReservaHora');
}).catch(function(error) {
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});

};

});
```

al problema es que de vez en cuando  en el servidor local de ionic sale el siguiente error:

> FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
>       at Z (http://localhost:8101/lib/firebase/firebase.js:54:364)
>       at a (http://localhost:8101/lib/firebase/firebase.js:52:69)
>       at Object.c [as auth] (http://localhost:8101/lib/firebase/firebase.js:53:461)
>       at http://localhost:8101/lib/angularfire/dist/angularfire.js:50:33
>       at Object. (http://localhost:8101/js/services.js:86:12)
>       at Object.invoke (http://localhost:8101/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18000:19)
>       at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (http://localhost:8101/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17839:37)
>       at Object.invoke (http://localhost:8101/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18000:19)
>       at http://localhost:8101/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17799:37
>       at getService (http://localhost:8101/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17946:39)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y la aplicación no funciona, se queda así como se ve en la imagen. Esto desde `ionic serve` al refrescar se soluciona. Pero al hacer un `ionic build ios` compilar y correr en el iphone la aplicación no funciona ni por si acaso, no entra al registrar y nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema es que la inicialización no debe ir en tu app.js, sino en el factory donde crearás la referencia. Intenta con los siguientes cambios:

**en `app.js` elimina la sentecia `firebase.initializeApp` y envia el `CONFIG` de parametro**

```
  .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
     $ionicPlatform.ready(function(CONFIG) {
```

**y en el factory ya podrás inicializar la referencia a firebase:**

```
.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",function($firebaseAuth) {
  firebase.initializeApp(CONFIG);
  var ref = firebase.database().ref();
  var auth = $firebaseAuth();
}
])
```

Comment: Gracias, funcionó y también probre de la manera más simple como lo indica en firebase y tmbn funcionó eso